# PHP Token Authentication - Expiration

Tags: php, rest, api, authentication

I have a hybrid SPA php web application that makes calls to a remote REST API for all it's needs. I'm starting to implement token authentication between the web server and api and I'm not quite sure how to handle expiration of the token. There may be some flaws in my design as well.

1. User submits login credentials (username & password) to the web server.
2. Web server sends call to the API.
3. API looks up creds., if good, a JWT Auth token is generated and returned to the web server where the Token is stored in a php session variable. The token is never made public.
4. Each call the web server makes to the api sends a request with an authorization header that includes the token pulled from the session.

My problem is, what's the best way to issue a new token if one has expired during an incoming request. The api checks each request's token to determine if it's valid and if it's expired. If the request API was GET foo/bar for example, expecting a JSON string in return, but the token has expired, what would be the expected behavior?

Hope this makes sense. Please let me know if I'm not clear enough. Have not had much luck researching this particular scenario.

Comment: It isn't very clear. Behaviour expected by whom?

Comment: If a request comes to the API to access a resource, but the token has expired, I assume a new token needs to be created and sent back to the webserver... however the webserver is expecting a json string with data, not a token. At what point in the process should I be pushing a new token back? Hope that clarfies

Comment: If the token has expired you have an authentication failure and the webserver handles that condition - since it's an expected condition in a system with temporary credentials. Of course, if you control these things yourself, a very sensible thing to ask yourself is do you really need a system with temporary, expiring credentials.

Comment: So that's the question. How do I handle such an authentication failure where the token is expired and a new one must be issued. Not sure how it would happen automatically as you're suggesting. For security purposes the token should need to be renewed as it's functioning as an API key..

Comment: I'm not sure what the difficulty is here. You return an auth error, the caller requests a new token. The problem with your scenario as described really is that it's just too abstract and lacks specifics.